# Flutter Unit Test Fails on Subclass

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, flutter-test

Method tested:

```
@override
  Future<Either<Failure, SampleModel>> getSampleModel(String activityType) async {
    if (await networkInfo.isConnected()) {
      final remoteModel = await remoteDataSource.getSampleModel(activityType);
      localDataSource.cacheSampleModel(remoteModel);
      return Right(remoteModel);
    } else {
      try {
        final localModel = await localDataSource.getSampleModel(activityType);
        return Right(localModel);
      } on CacheException {
        return Left(CacheFailure());
      }
    }
  }
```

Trying to test the failure scenario on the `localDataSource`.

The class structure for the failures looks like this:

```
abstract class Failure {
  Exception? exception;

  Failure() : exception = null;
}

class CacheFailure extends Failure {}
```

Simple enough, I think. And here is my test:

```
test(
      'should return failure when the call to remote data source is unsuccessful',
      () async {
    // arrange
    when(mockNetworkInfo.isConnected()).thenAnswer((_) async => false);
    when(mockLocalDataSource.getSampleModel(any)).thenThrow(CacheException());
    // act
    final result = await repository.getSampleModel(activityType);
    // assert
    verifyZeroInteractions(mockRemoteDataSource);
    verify(mockLocalDataSource.getSampleModel(activityType));
    expect(result, Left(CacheFailure()));
  });
```

The last line fails with this error:

> Expected: Left<CacheFailure, dynamic>:<Left(Instance of
> 'CacheFailure')>
>  Actual: Left<Failure, SampleModel>:<Left(Instance
> of 'CacheFailure')>

I'm confused since the method clearly returns a `CacheFailure` but the test suggests that I am returning the super class `Failure`. Further, why does this matter? A `CacheFailure` is a `Failure`.

Probably a simple oversight, but I just can't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `expect` simply compares `result == Left(CacheFailure())` in my thought.

How about using `isA<Left<Failure, SampleModel>>()` matcher?

Answer (score -1):

The following works for those who still search for a Solution:

```
result.fold((l) => {expect(l, isA<ServerFailure>())}, (r) => {expect(r, null)});
```

Comment: this answer makes no sense as ServerFailure isn't even mentioned in the question.